# Font Not Installed on Client Machine

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I used some special fonts in my asp.net web application .Which are not found on every machine (which use that web application) and due to which that font is not visible to client.how can i resolve it

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this W3Schools article](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp) you should always specify fallbacks when specifying a font-family:

> The font-family property should hold several font names as a
>   "fallback" system. If the browser does not support the first font, it
>   tries the next font, and so on.
>
> Start with the font you want, and end with a generic family, to let
>   the browser pick a similar font in the generic family, if no other
>   fonts are available.

You can do this in CSS with the `font-family` property, simply by specifying a comma separated list of different fonts. As mentioned above it should end with a generic family.

The following example prefers `Arial`, but falls back to the `Helvetica` "font-family" when `Arial` is not found. If neither of both is available it then falls back to a font of the `sans serif` "generic-family".

```
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a webfont in this case. The browser will download your specific font and display the page as you want.

See for instance (never used, first hit in Google search): https://www.web-font-generator.com/ Mind the second checkbox!

Or see https://www.google.com/fonts